# What is IntelliJ's equivalent of Eclipse's .metadata folder? Which program produces less of these files?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, metadata, dropbox

I've been told that IntelliJ has a .metadata equivalent, but I was wondering are people referring to the .idea folder? More importantly, **are IntelliJ's metadata files scarce or abundant** compared to Eclipse's metadata files?

My problem is that **Eclipse's .metadatas tend to have hundreds, even thousands of files which are a huge inconvenience for me** (more on that later).

I've imported my projects into an IntelliJ project and they've all succesfully run. I noticed that the .idea folder does not use a lot of space or contain a lot of files. However, **having spent a lot of time on Eclipse, I know that the metadata files gradually grow in size and quantity. A new user (me) can not use his own experience to verify that**

The reason why this is an inconvenience for me is that **I sync some of my Eclipse projects to dropbox and to my other hard drive.** To be clear I do not use backup utilities which is different from syncing as I need my files to be changed and backed up bidirectionally. The problem is that **syncing multiple files seems to be very time inefficient**. Even syncing a single large file is inefficient, but it seems to take significantly less time. As a result, I can no longer efficiently code some programs in Eclipse (especially in dropbox because it's even slower to transmit data to the cloud).

So here are my numbered questions:

1. Does IntelliJ's .metadata equivalent take as much space?
2. Does IntelliJ generate more files or less files compared to Eclipse?
3. Where are the metadata files stored?

If I have 4000 metadata files, I was hoping IntelliJ produces a factor of 1/10 of that amount. That would make my life much easier.

Comment: For Eclipse reducing the Local History size can help limit the metadata size (Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History)

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'm going to try this out and see if this makes a huge difference. Edit: I just changed it. You can't have a smaller size than 1 MB which is the default, but at least you can reduce from 50 to something like 25.

Comment: You should be looking into using a SCM instead of Dropbox.

Comment: I don't need to look into it. I already use Git for source code control and management. Every time I mention my use of dropbox to store or transfer software, people assume I am clueless about source control, which I already use.

The reason why I use dropbox for certain things is because I only need the latest build only for myself, and I need those changes to by synced as soon as I hit the save button.

Comment: Additionally, not only do I need to keep my code and files uploaded, but I need the project settings and metadata to by synced.

Comment: IntelliJ's meta-data is stored in a directory named ".idea" in the root of the project. As far as which has more files / larger files, why not try it out (IntelliJ's community edition is free), and let us know?